# Season's champion

Tags: tournament, metagame

We play once a week with the same gaming group, each night a different game.  I thought about creating "season" records, such that every ~3 months we will announce the season's champion.  The prize will be the right to choose the next game that we will buy together.  This is basically a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament) starching over several months.

**How to build such a tournament?**

1. How to aggregate the results of several games?
2. Should the scores be (4,3,2,1) for first, second, third, forth respectably ?
3. How to factor in games' weight (some are 4 hours long and some are half an hour fillers)?
4. Will this season record make the playing experience better?  I am concerned about the case where some players are out of the race before we are close to the end of the season
5. Players will be harsh on the season leader even if he is doing bad in the current game.  Overall do you think that this metagame **improves the playing experience**?

**EDIT:**  We play mostly medium games like: Great Western Trail, Food Chain Magnate, Blood Rage, Azul, Eclipse, Clans of Caledonia, Mombasa, The Gallerist, and our favorite is 
[Nations: Dynasties](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/180539/nations-dynasties)

most nights we are the same people, some nights another friend joins.

Comment: Is it always the same people, or is attendance a little variable?  Also, what do you mean by 3 (big/medium/light)?  Time to play?

Comment: I think (5) is a serious problem. I've been in that position before (in Risk Legacy which tracks total wins and I had the most wins up till that point) and it was frustrating and less fun (for me at least) to have everyone teaming up on me from the start.

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on what types of games you are playing as some of them won't work well with a ranking system. Providing some examples of what games you are thinking of will help.

Comment: Doing this could create a kingmaker in the later rounds if I know I can win as long I do better then player x.  Also not all games really tell your true strength at the end of the game.   I would suggest just keeping it casual or doing a legacy game where it is part of the mechanics of the game.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a system where each game night has 20 points to allocate.  You divide the points between the number of times you play that game. (e.g. You play a game 2 times, 10 points for each game).

The allocation of the points is:
~25% to winner, ~15% to second place, ~20% each to three achievements.

The set amount of points fits #1.

The scores for wins/close wins are consistent (#2).

Balances out big/medium/short games (#3).

Since the achievement points are such a big portion, you can catch up even if you don't win (#4).

By making winning less valuable than it normally is, ganging up on the leader can backfire, since they can go for achievements instead of wins. (#5)

(Achievements is a shameless steal of Mario Party).

For achievements, I'd say make a pool and pick randomly.  And you can do that before/after the game (after, if you want more random).

Comment: What are the Achievements and how do one gets them?

Comment: @Cohensius For Catan, it could be most settlements at end of game, fewest cities, most/fewest ports, most roads not part of longest road, most dev cards bought, most times stolen from, most roads, most knights, etc. Get creative.

Comment: Interesting idea!  
Do you think this question should be closed?  Definitely there are some do's and donts for setting a tournament.